# Trouble accessing data member between classes

Tags: c++, class, organization

I have two classes; a player class and a match class.  I want the player to be able to use all of its member functions; carry, capture, etc, but its member functions need to know about the match class data members; board, opponent, challenger without making those data members public.

If you can not find a good solution or confused as to what I am asking, I would still be interested in advice on class organization.

**mancala.h**

```
#ifndef MANCALA_H
#define MANCALA_H

#include <string>
#include <random>

namespace mancala{  

    class player{
        public:
            void carry(int pit);
            void capture(const int& pit);
            bool madeStore(const int& pit)const;
            bool madeCapture(const int& pit)const; 
            bool madeValidMove(const int& pit)const;
            bool madeSideClear()const;
            bool operator==(const player& p)const;
        private:
            std::string tag;
    };

    class match{
        public:
            match(const int& match_ID = 0) : board{4,4,4,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0}{
                if(match_ID){
                    ;
                }
                else{
                    this->turn = randPlayer();
                    this->status = "make move";
                }
            };
            void begin();
            void end();
            void save();
            bool update();
        private:
            player challenger, opponent, turn;
            static const int seeds = 48;
            static const int pits  = 14;
            std::string status;
            int board[pits];
            void nextTurn();
            player randPlayer();
    };
}

#endif//MANCALA_H
```

**Example from: mancala.cpp**

```
void player::carry(int pit)
{
    if(this->madeValidMove(pit) == false){
        status = "invalid move";
    }
    else{

        int hand = board[pit];

        board[pit] = 0;

        for(hand; hand != 0; hand--){  

            if(pit == 13){
                pit = 0;
            }
            else{
                pit++;  
            }
             //Skips opponent store
            if(pit == 13 && turn == challenger){
                pit = 0;
            }//Skips challenger store
            else if(pit == 6 && turn == opponent){
                pit++;
            }
             //If placing last seed check where it is being placed
            if(hand == 1){
                 //Store
                if(this->madeStore(pit)){
                    board[pit]++;
                    status = "free move";
                }//Capture
                else if(this->madeCapture(pit)){
                    this->capture(pit);
                  nextTurn();
                }//Normal
                else{
                    board[pit]++;
                    nextTurn();
                }
            }//Placing seed
            else{
                board[pit]++;
            }
        }

        if(this->madeSideClear()){
            end();
        }
    }   

    save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the match class a friend of the player class.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class

> A friend class in C++ can access the "private" and "protected" members of the class in which it is declared as a friend.